# the set is not wroking/finding elements

Tags: c++, set, find

i am trying to build a set that sorts line segments according to their places , [for example : the green segment is above the blue one thats why it comes first in the set, and after their intersection i swap their places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycm0p.png)

regarding the sorting , in the operator <
I'm checking which segment starts last and comparing it to the intersection of the lines that the segments are part of
if the starting point comes before the intersection then I'm comparing the y of the first segment' starting point with the y that comes from placing first segment's x in the other segment's line function .
if the starting point comes after the intersection then I'm checking which segment ends first and comparing the y of it's ending point with the y that comes from placing this segment's x in the other segment's line function
and that's how I'm sorting it

```
bool operator<(const SweepLineS &s) const {
    float x = PointOfIntersection(segment, s.segment, 1, 1).p.x;
    if (segment.source.x > s.segment.source.x) {
        if(segment.source.x < x){//before point of intersection
            return lineFromPoints(s.segment.source, s.segment.taregt, segment.source.x) < segment.source.y;
        } else {
            if (segment.taregt.x <= s.segment.taregt.x)
                return lineFromPoints(s.segment.source, s.segment.taregt, segment.taregt.x) < segment.taregt.y;
            else return  s.segment.taregt.y < lineFromPoints(segment.source, segment.taregt, s.segment.taregt.x);
        }
    } else {
        if(s.segment.source.x < x){//before point of intersection
            return lineFromPoints(segment.source, segment.taregt, s.segment.source.x) > s.segment.source.y;
        } else {
            if (s.segment.taregt.x <= segment.taregt.x) {
                return lineFromPoints(segment.source, segment.taregt, s.segment.taregt.x) > s.segment.taregt.y;
            }
            else return lineFromPoints(s.segment.source, s.segment.taregt, segment.taregt.x) < segment.taregt.y;
        }
    }
}
```

regarding swapping the places, i swap the segments places in the set by removing them and cutting them and adding them again so that their new starting point is the intersection point
the "sweepLine_S_Set" is the name of the set.

```
auto index2It = sweepLineintSet.find({ev.s2,ev.j});
        auto s2It = sweepLine_S_Set.find({index2It->segment, index2It->index});
        sweepLine_S_Set.erase(s2It);
        sweepLineintSet.erase(index2It);
        auto index1It = sweepLineintSet.find({ev.s1,ev.i});
        auto s1It = sweepLine_S_Set.find({index1It->segment, index1It->index});
        sweepLine_S_Set.erase(s1It);
        sweepLineintSet.erase(index1It);

        if(ev.s1.taregt.y > ev.s2.taregt.y) {
            high = sweepLine_S_Set.insert({{ev.p, ev.s1.taregt}, ev.i}).first;
            low = sweepLine_S_Set.insert({{ev.p, ev.s2.taregt}, ev.j}).first;
            sweepLineintSet.insert({{ev.p, ev.s1.taregt}, ev.i});
            sweepLineintSet.insert({{ev.p, ev.s2.taregt}, ev.j});
        } else if(ev.s2.taregt.y > ev.s1.taregt.y) {
            low = sweepLine_S_Set.insert({{ev.p, ev.s1.taregt}, ev.i}).first;
            auto no = sweepLine_S_Set.insert({{ev.p, ev.s2.taregt}, ev.j});
            high =no.first;
            auto what = no.second;
            sweepLineintSet.insert({{ev.p, ev.s1.taregt}, ev.i});
            sweepLineintSet.insert({{ev.p, ev.s2.taregt}, ev.j});
        }
```

my code also includes a stack that represent events each event is an endpoint or an intersection point
first I save the end points in the stack by sorting them by their x's and then i go through the stack and whenever i find a new intersection i add the new event to the stack ,
whenever i get to an intersection event (when going through the stack) i swap the segments using the above code , and there comes the problem, the function "find" doese not find every segment i am looking for
for example when i run a code that represents these segments

[starting from left to the right as you see the first intersection point is between the green and blue one and there happens the first swapping which works fine, the next intersection point is between the two black ones and there when I want to remove the first segment for the swapping "find" doesn't find the wanted segment (the black one above)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAyol.png)

I searched and found that my problem is in defining the operator < but i cant figure out what i am doing wrong .

Comment: This could definitely use a [mre] and a bit more information about what you mean by "not working". Please make a reduced but complete example that people could run and see the problem in action.

Comment: With the code as it currently is we don't know what PointOfIntersection and lineFromPoints do. And the core idea seems somewhat dubious to me, can you actually make a sensible strict ordering on objects in a 2d plane?

Comment: that is also a problem , I am trying to implement a sweepline algorithm that is why i need to sort them but cant figure more thourough way

Comment: i'm relying on the fact that if the y of segment1 is higher than the y of segment2 then segment1 is above segment2 until we pass the intersection point.

Comment: If your relation is not a valid https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/strict_weak_order , std::set will get confused if you try to use it with it.